# Trying to store and retrieve objects from a svelte store

Tags: javascript, arrays, push, store, svelte

I am playing around with the svelte store in the svelte docs env[svelte Stores/autosubscription](https://svelte.dev/tutorial/auto-subscriptions).

I am actually trying to add objects to an array named scores. My code is the following.

App.svelte

```html
<script>
    import { scores } from './stores.js';
    import Incrementer from './Incrementer.svelte';
    import Decrementer from './Decrementer.svelte';
    import Resetter from './Resetter.svelte';   
</script>
 
<h1>The count is:</h1>
{#each $scores as score, i}
<ul>
    <li>
        name: {score.name}
    </li>
    <li>
        score: {score.score}
    </li>
    <li>
        maxScore: {score.maxScore}
    </li>   
</ul>
{/each}

<Incrementer/>
<Decrementer/>
<Resetter/>
```

Incrementer.svelte

```html
<script>
    import { scores } from './stores.js';

    function increment() {
        count.update(n => n.push(n[0]));
    }
</script>

<button on:click={increment}>
    +
</button>
```

Resetter.svelte

```html
<script>
    import { scores } from './stores.js';

    function reset() {
        scores.set([{
            name: 'name',
            score: 1,
            maxScore: 1
        },{
            name: 'anderer',
            score: 4,
            maxScore: 8
        }]);
    }
</script>

<button on:click={reset}>
    reset
</button>
```

and finally the stores.js

```js
import { writable } from 'svelte/store';

export const scores = writable([{name: 'NAME', score: 1000, maxScore: 3000}]);
```

(I left out the Decrementer.svelte which is identically to Incrementer.svelte but implements n.pop)

What my problem is, that the Incrementer and Decrementer do not change the $scores viewed in the Result window.

I've also tried to push an object in the Incrementer.svelte:

```js
function increment() {
        count.update(n => n.push({name: 'name', score: 2, maxScore: 3}));
    }
```

The reset code does work as I intended.

Can someone please tell me, what I am missing here?

Thank you!

Answer (score 2):

Where missing some context here

```js
count.update(n => n.push(n[0]));
```

`count` isn't defined in any of the snippets, i assume you meant scores.update

The return of the callback passed to update becomes the new value, in case of a push that will be a number (the new length of the array) not the new array.

I expected to see a

```js
scores.update(n => { n.push(n[0]); return n});
// or
scores.update(n => [...n, n[0]]);
// or
$scores = [...$scores, $scores[0]];
```

To debug a store, write the following line in a component:

```js
$: console.log($scores);
```

Comment: Just oversaw this, thanks for pointing on it!